# Save html5 canvas element to file (local)

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, html5-canvas

I'm doing a webapp on Android, and I've a HTML5 Canvas on which an user can draw what he wants using touch events. And I would like to save this on a sdcard, so in local. And can't use any server side script (php etc) to do that stuff.

I'm using a `magictouch.js` example :

```
    <canvas id="example" height=450 width=300></canvas> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="magictouch.js"></script>

    <script> 

    var CanvasDrawr = function(options) {

    var canvas = document.getElementById(options.id),
    ctxt = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img     = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");


    ctxt.lineWidth = options.size || Math.ceil(Math.random() * 35);
    ctxt.lineCap = options.lineCap || "round";
    ctxt.pX = undefined;
    ctxt.pY = undefined;

    var lines = [,,];
     var offset = $(canvas).offset();

    var self = {
    //bind click events
    init: function() {

    canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', self.preDraw, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', self.draw, false);

    },

    preDraw: function(event) {
            $.each(event.touches, function(i, touch) {
              var id = touch.identifier;
              lines[id] = { x     : this.pageX - offset.left, 
                y     : this.pageY - offset.top, 
                color : options.color || ["black"] 
              };
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  },

  draw: function(event) {
    var e = event, hmm = {};

    $.each(event.touches, function(i, touch) {
      var id = touch.identifier;
      var moveX = this.pageX - offset.left - lines[id].x,
      moveY = this.pageY - offset.top - lines[id].y;

      var ret = self.move(id, moveX, moveY);
      lines[id].x = ret.x;
      lines[id].y = ret.y;
    });

    event.preventDefault();
  },

  move: function(i, changeX, changeY) {
    ctxt.strokeStyle = lines[i].color;
    ctxt.beginPath();
    ctxt.moveTo(lines[i].x, lines[i].y);

    ctxt.lineTo(lines[i].x + changeX, lines[i].y + changeY);
    ctxt.stroke();
    ctxt.closePath();

    return { x: lines[i].x + changeX, y: lines[i].y + changeY };
  }
};

    return self.init();
    };

    $(function(){
var super_awesome_multitouch_drawing_canvas_thingy = new CanvasDrawr({id:"example", size: 2 }); 
console.log('loaded');
      });

    </script> 
    </body>
```

But all examples which I met on Internet were used with a php script on a server to decode and save the canva as an image. And actually just want to do that on my Android device, in my sdcard, by just using HTML5/Javascript...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check nihilogic library ?
http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

It use toDataUrl() function so you may get an ugly name of pictures but still you will have a picture.

You also can use downloadify but it use flash and I know flash is not often on android, depend your case https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

Also I, like kbok, don't know phoneGap but you could probably try to use both context.toDataUrl() and fwrite.

Comment: What I do is :
(...)
    
    var img64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/data:image\/png;base64,/, '');
    var img_ok = decode_base64(img);

    navigator.notification.alert(img_ok);
 writer.write(img_ok, true);
 writer.close();

}


But my png file is corrupted. :/

Comment: btw canvas2image seems pretty cool, but I don't want to prompt the user to save the image, if I could avoid that it could be nice

Comment: Yup just tested, that's not what i'm really looking for. Because I just want to write the PNG file, and Canvas2Image force the prompt.

Comment: I don't get why your replace data:image/png
You want to change replace "image/octet-stream" to base64 before writing it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible since you do not have access to the filesystem from a web page (Except some edge cases, which are not useful here).

What I would advise, of course, is to use the server to generate this file. Since it's not possible, you may find a way to execute "native" code on the client by using a plugin, or a Java applet.

Comment: My webapp is in fact inside a native app, since I use Phonegap I still have an apk file and access to natives APIs. So thats not 'only' a webapp. I can't use fopen/fwrite for that usage? (I tried but nothing happens).

Comment: Well I don't know phonegap so I'm afraid I can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you convert the  to an image on the server side and then allow the user to download the image onto their phone?

Comment: Hi,

Because this is a customer's signature and that I have to manage when the user is offline, so I have to store the img for a while.
I'm now more advanced in my project. I can get the canvas encoded in base64, I tried to decode it but now my png file seems corrupted.